# algorithm for reducing/merging nominal and ordinal categories

Tags: algorithm, r, categories, ordinal

I'm receiving datasets where several variables have >10 categories (some ordinal/some nominal) and I suspect that several of the categories could be merged, both for easier presentation but also to gain enough events for analysis. This could/should be done with a priori knowledge, but an algorithm simplifying the process would be very welcome. Does such an algorithm exist? Is this implemented in R?

edit:

```
data("GBSG2", package = "ipred")
cut(GBSG2$tsize,seq(0,100,10))->GBSG2$size
```

Now I´d like to find whether any of the categories and which categories in GBSG2$size or GBSG2$tgrade can be merged without a significant loss of information in their ability to predict GBSG2$cens status. I know I could do it manually by merging several of the categories in the two variables, running the logistic regression and comparing the results before and after merging the variables manually, but is there any other methods?

Comment: Do you mean cross-tabulation? Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: At the top of my head I cannot give a very good reproducible example.confer the edit above. I do not mean cross-tabulations..

Comment: In it's current state I'm voting to close the question as "too vague". There is no way that we can read your mind to come up with a strategy for aggregating with no information about how the data is structured and no guidance about what would make sense.

Comment: I'd still start with a crosstabulation.   Then throw away the empty cells. (and maybe re-enumerate the remaining non-empty cells) The nicest outcome of this would be rows or columns with only one non-empty cell.

Comment: I agree with 'close.'  The OP needs to explain what 'nominal' and 'ordinal' mean to him.

Comment: Nominal and ordinal have no special meaning to the OP. Just the usual statistical meaning, IMHO. I'd also like to point the OP to decision trees and Quinlan's  ID3 and C4.5 algorithms (GIYF).

Comment: By nominal I mean factor values that are not ordered, in contrast to ordinal where there is an intrinsic ordering. However not on an interval scale. I thought ordinal and nominal were rather unambigous terms? Appreciate the links to ID3 and C4.5. I also found the CHAID algorithm that is implemented in R on R-forge by Hothorn et al.